# Laravel 5 select current drop down and remainders in laravel collective

Tags: php, laravel, laravelcollective

In a laravel controller I currently have these two variables which are pulling from a their respective models.

```
$guests = Person::where('id', $id)
                  ->with('languages')
                  ->get();

        $languages = Language::pluck('name')->toArray();

        return view('layouts.visitor', ['guests' => $guests, 'languages' => $languages]);
```

in the database table I have a few different fields:

```
id | name
----------
1  | spanish
2  | english
3  | french
```

When selecting a language I'm able to select a language assigned to a user.  I am also able to select all the languages in the table.  What I would like to do and I'm not able to figure out is to have it show the current language assigned to a user first when he page loads then after if the user would like to change it they should view all the OTHER languages available in the drop down.

If the default language for this user was spanish it should be like this:

```
Drop down:
Spanish
English
French
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `selected` attribute to the dropdown option if that is the user's chosen language:

```
<select name="language">
  @foreach($languages as $language)
  <option value="{{$language->id}}" @if($user->language_id == $language->id) selected @endif>{{$language->name}}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using `one to many` relationship. And your `persons` table has a `language_id` column which is foreign key of `languages` table.

In that case your controller should look like this:

```
public function show($id){
    $guests = Person::query()->findOrFail($id); //find a row with an id

    $languages = Language::pluck('name','id'); //'name' is the value and 'id' the key of the array

    return view('layouts.visitor', ['guests' => $guests, 'languages' => $languages]);
}
```

**Blade:**

In blade keep the default value null. It will retrieve the value of `language_id` column from database.

```
{{ Form::select('language_id',$languages,null,['otherAttribute'=>'ifAny']) }}
```

Comment: this kicks an error: Trying to get property of non-object  @smartrahat

Comment: I think the problem is somewhere else. Can you share your blade file?

Comment: I ended up doing it just like this: {!! Form::select('name', $languages, $guest->primary_language, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!} @smartrahat

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter of the [**`select`**](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html#drop-down-lists) method is responsible for selecting the current related property. So like [smartrahat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49394386/1592845) answer, you will correct your `pluck` to be `..pluck('name','id')` then in view:

```
{{ Form::select('language_id',$languages,$guests->language,['class' => 'form-control']) }}
```

This solution assumes that there a property for `Person` model named language and it should be the language id integer.